# Tier 4 dependent Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa, children, nigerian-citizens

I am a student with a Tier 4 visa. I just had a baby in the UK. Can I apply for my baby dependent visa here in the UK or do I have to go back to my country to apply for her visa?

My husband is not here with me as a dependent. I am here all by myself. My husband does not intend to join me here as I plan to go back by the end of the year.

I need to travel to America with my baby for a short holiday. I would need my baby to have a visa as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply in the UK for the dependent visa for your child. https://www.gov.uk/tier-4-general-visa/family-members